# Broadwell and Lubuntu 14.10

Tags: lubuntu

i5-5200U Prozessor
Intel® HD Graphics 5500

I bought an Aspire v3-371 for my girlfriend.
I installes Lubuntu 14.10 on it, and kernel 3.18.5.

Also I enable d[xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) ppa.

With stock lubuntu, I had some problems with freezing gui, so I installed the newer kernel, which I am using on 2 Haswell systems with no problem.

I also added xorg-edgers - after which I think it got some better.

But how to get the newest Intel drivers? I know it should be included into the kernel, but I guess it still hase some issues.
Should I download from 01.org and undo xorg-edgers and kernel 3.18?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually, I just installed a newer kernel (3.19 at this time), and almost all my problems are gone.

Also I switched to Ubuntu 15.04.